# Conveying the idea of « go figure »

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, grec

En grec nous avons une expression « τρέχα γύρευε » (see, look for, search for, figure out) ([trecha gyreve](https://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CF%84%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%B1)) ; on le dit de quelque chose qui est incompréhensible ou très difficile à expliquer.
L'expression idiomatique la plus voisine que je puisse trouver est l'anglais (américain) *go figure*. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_figure

> go figure
>
> (idiomatic) Expresses perplexity, puzzlement, or surprise (as if telling somebody to try to make sense of the situation).
>
> The car wouldn't start yesterday no matter what I did, but today it works just fine. Go figure.

En fait, c’est un raccourci pour *go and figure (that) out*.

Quelles tournures idiomatiques expriment des idées similaires en français ?

La suivante fait-elle partie du lot ?

> Allez comprendre

Est-elle idiomatique ?

Comment: *Allez comprendre* convient bien sûr. On peut compléter: *allez y comprendre quelque chose*. Le *Va-t-en savoir* proposé par @aCOSwt convient très bien aussi.   Quelques variantes: *va (allez) savoir*, *Dieu seul le sait*.

Comment: @Damien : Je trouve le *Dieu seul le sait* un peu trop *statique* dans ce cas précis comparé à la dynamique (la course) suggérée par par τρέχα

Comment: @One1 Voir la version éditée.

Comment: @aCOSwt Effectivement, il me manquait cette notion de mouvement. Maintenant, pour avoir l'avis de Dieu, il faut se déplacer aussi

Comment: @Damien Voir la version éditée pour le verbe τρέχα.

Comment: @Damien : lol! Oui! Tu as bien raison mais... le moins vite possible... de préférence... ;-)

Comment: @Damien Je crois que votre commentaire mérite le statut de réponse:-)!

Comment: va savoir Charles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En direct du grec et full credits to Agnès Salvaterra : ***Va-t-en savoir***

Comment: WOW! Eυχαριστώ πολύ!

Comment: @Dimitris : Παρακαλώ! ;-)

Comment: C'est peut-être une subtilité régionale, mais je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu récemment cette expression ; on lui préfère plutôt **"Va savoir"** (qui est exactement la même chose en substance...)

Answer (score 8):

*Allez comprendre* convient bien sûr.

On peut compléter: *allez y comprendre quelque chose*.

Le *Va-t-en savoir* proposé par @aCOSwt convient très bien aussi. Une variante: *va (allez) savoir*, proposé par @LPH.

J'avais proposé en commentaire une expression très courante, *Dieu seul le sait*, mais il manque ici la notion de mouvement.

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller_savoir).

Comment: @0ne1 Merci. A noter que *va comprendre* est bien cité comme synonyme de *va savoir*

Comment: @Damien J'ai un exemple dans lequel les deux ne sont pas interchangeables (dernier exemple de ma réponse); je crois qu'ils ne sont jamais synonymes et qu'ils sont seulement *compatibles* dans un assez grand nombre de contextes.

Comment: @LPH Effectivement dans votre dernier exemple, les deux expressions sont possibles, mais le sens sera différent.

Comment: @Damien Je ne vois pas ça du tout. Quel sens donner à ce dialogue avec « comprendre »?

Comment: @LPH "Il se peut qu'ils aillent travailler demain". *Va savoir* -> Peut-être qu'ils n'iront pas travailler, on ne sait pas. *Va comprendre* -> on ne sait pas pourquoi ils iront travailler. C'est en tout cas ainsi que je le comprends.

Comment: @Damien Peut-être voulez-vous dire que "Il se peut qu'ils aillent travailler demain" est dit avec le sous-entendu « ce serait chose surprenante » ? Oui, c'est un peu plus compliqué mais pas vraiment exceptionnel.

Answer (score 5):

En plus des expressions proches de *go figure* par le mouvement et exprimées sous forme d'impératif, il y a aussi une expression légèrement humoristique pour exprimer la perplexité devant un phénomène inexpliqué: *mystère et boule de gomme*.

> Ma voiture ne démarrait plus, et aujourd'hui voilà qu'elle démarre sans problème ! Mystère et boule de gomme !

Answer (score 4):

That's the right idea; it is idiomatic. There is some variety in French as to what can follow the verb "to go"; nevertheless, the use of these additional forms is subject to context.

- **[Allez/va] [comprendre (pourquoi)/savoir (pourquoi)/vous le demander/vous le figurer/vous demander pourquoi/vous figurer pourquoi]**

In order to use the last two possibilities there must be a preceding  question, from either one of the locutors or an assertion that shows something abnormal, unusual, strange, etc. or that enunciates a possibility.

The examples below will point out some of the correspondences between form and context; often though, which you can use is a matter of common sense.

- — Pourquoi mettent-ils des plumes à leurs bandeaux ?
  — Va savoir…
  (*Also*)  va te le demander/va te le figurer
  (*Here*, "savoir pourquoi" *is possible but unusual, slightly redondent.*)
- — C'est bizarre, qu'est-ce qui les empêche de faire leur travail ?
  — Allez vous le demander…
  (*As the question is of the "what" sort, you can't use the "why" forms.*)
- La maison était couverte de feuilles de plastic et ils ne voulaient pas nous laisser entrer, allez comprendre.
  (*Also*) allez vous demander pourquoi, allez vous figurer pourquoi
  (*Here, « savoir » is not likely.*)
- — Il se peut qu'ils aillent travailler demain. (*dit dans un contexte de pure possibility*)¹
  — Allez savoir…
  (*Here, only* "savoir" *will do*.)

¹ Commentaire ajouté en révision après remarque de 
user [Damien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40442/conveying-the-idea-of-go-figure/40445?noredirect=1#comment81380_40445)

Comment: Et peut-être le *va* tout court rend-il correctement le *go* anglosaxon mais.. il est à mon sens insuffisant à rendre le *τρέχα* grec.

Comment: @0ne1 Il me semble bien avoir entendu ce verbe dans cette construction, en particulier dans des versions plus longues: « Allez-vous figurer pourquoi ils ne travaillent pas ? ». Ce qui me fait douter aussi qu'il n'y a pas de confusion et de cas d'anglicisme c'est que je ne connaissais pas l'expression américaine, qui n'a été introduite dans le langage que vers la fin du XXe siècle (https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25103/349876).

Comment: Je ne crois pas, je crois que _figurer_ pour trouver une solution est un anglicisme basé sur _to figure/to figure out_ mais tu pourrais poser la question. Voir [ici](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/vocabulaire/ang_decouvrez_les_anglicismes.html). Je parle anglais depuis un quart de siècle et _go figure_ n'est pas du tout inhabituel pour moi en anglais américain, mais ce n'est pas la question, sauf que je comprends ce qui t'amène à penser ce que tu expliques.

Comment: @0ne1 J'ose croire que vous ne faites pas la confusion avec simplement « figurer », le verbe utilisé est le verbe pronominal « se figurer » ; cet anglicisme qui est examiné ne fait pas partie de mon idiolecte en erreur.

Comment: Compare « Allez-vous figurer... » avec « allez vous figurer ».

Comment: @0ne1 Oui, bien sûr, c'est une erreur, je corrige. Merci.